Encoding issue using FluentEmail in .NET 6
I am using FluentEmail v3.0.2 to send mails using HTML templates in a .NET 6 project.
I use HTML templates to which I add dynamic variables :
var email = await Email
                    .From(insertTemplateValues.SenderEmail,insertTemplateValues.SenderName)
                    .To(recipient)
                    .Subject("Subject")
                    .UsingTemplate(this._templateService.Template("HTMLFile"), new { requestId = requestId, title = this.decode64(title)})
                    .SendAsync();

I decode from b64 my title because it is encoded by a previous service :
 private string decode64(string encodedString)
 {
            byte[] base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
 }

In my mails, I have the data I want but all accented characters from dynamic data are replaced by "�".
Example :

You can notice that only the dynamic data has issue with accented characters.
The HTML template :
@model dynamic
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html {font-family: 'Arial';}

        .primary {color: #e84315;}

        .bold {font-weight: bold;}
    </style>

</head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="primary">Demande #@Model.requestId</h2>
        <br />
        La demande <span class="bold">#@Model.requestId : @Model.title</span> a été créée et envoyé
   </body>
</html>

I put the meta tag to the HTML file, I encoded into UTF-8 after decoding the b64, I read in the documentation that by default FluentEmail uses UTF-8.
I have no idea how to solve this anymore. Do you have any idea ?

Can you add some debugging info? Such as what title contains and what the result of passing it through your decode64 method.

Is there a chance the Base64 encoded text already contains the unicode replacement characters?

@phuzi you were right... the problem was due to my Angular frontend. I was using the btoa method which can cause problems with accents. Debugging was the key
